# How can I override the fan to have it run 24/7?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

How can I override the fan ON 24/7? Can I do this by putting a jumper at the thermostat between R & G and leave it there without a problem?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, jumping R and G will turn on the fan but I have to ask *why* would you do this. Most thermostats have a FAN ON switch that will do what the jumpers would do. Adding jumpers are good for testing and troubleshooting but it's never a good idea to leave them in permanently.

Comment: Generally speaking, there *aren't* protections (other than short cycling) in thermostats, and the air handler will protect itself from issues like motor failure even with jumpers installed (remember that a dumb round thermostat is just a few funny switches and a bimetal)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  You're right. The fuse in my thermostat only protects it, nothing else.  I liked that dumb round Honeywell .. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Jumpering R to G will stick the fan on 24x7.

From the furnace's perspective, it will run the fan when one of two things is true: G is shunted to R.  Or when it determines the heat exchanger is hot enough to run the fan (to not blow cool air around the house in the meantime).

It sounds like you have the most basic possible 2-wire thermostat.  [For $5 more than the thermostat you have](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Honeywell-Home-Economy-Non-Programmable-Thermostat-with-1H-1C-Single-Stage-Heating-and-Cooling-CT31A/100400017), you can get a thermostat with a little switch that says "Fan: auto/on".

In the "on" position, the fan will be on 24x7. In the "auto" position, the fan will be on when the furnace wants it on.

Now why is the thermostat even given access to G? How does it work with A/C?

Well, the furnace has no idea the house is even equipped with A/C.  So the only way the furnace knows to run its fan is that the thermostat tells it to... on the G wire.

By the way, if the wiring to the thermostat is only 2-wire, all this is moot.

Comment: "Or, the heat exchanger is hot enough to warrant running the fan." In a lock-out from an overheat, yes. But AFAIK it's a digital delay timer on the board. Plenum overheat sensor is only part of the safety chain - it's not being monitored in any way or by anything else. Citation for 'heat exchanger is hot enough' to call the blower. ? (I've been looking for a cite on this for a while)

Comment: By the way, if the wiring to the thermostat is only 2-wire, all this [stuff about new t-stats] is moot [but you can always just put a jumper in the unit].

Comment: @Mazura I can't... removed. I find it difficult to believe anyone would use a 2-wire thermostat cable.